# jQuery not working correctly on click, only one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble getting this to work correctly, you can see the code below, it seems like it is only working for one link, it will just load index.php?act=old...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#example").dialog({modal: true});
        $("#example").dialog({width: 500});

        $('#newProject').click(function(){
            $('#dialogContent').load('index.php?act=new');
        });

        $('#oldProject').click(function(){
            $('#dialogContent').load('index.php?act=old');
        });

    });
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="example" title="Create new project or open old project?" style="display:none">
<div id="dialogContent">
Would you like to create a new calculation or open and edit and old calculation?<br /><br />
<a href="#" id="oldProject">Open Old Calculation</a><br /><br /><a href="#" id="newProject">Create New Calculation</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure both links work? Does JS step into the event handlers at all?

Comment: Either one I click the ?act=old is the only one that will load into the dialogcontent DIV

Comment: I am testing it locally with XAMPP

Comment: are those links inserted dynamically into the page, or are they there when jquery executes its domready event?

Comment: I added 2 more line of code, the dialog loads when the page is opened

Comment: It works for me :http://jsfiddle.net/3rfj9vuh/
why are you using `display:none` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to disable the default behavior of the link:

```
$('#newProject').click(function(event)
{
     event.preventDefault();
     $('#dialogContent').load('index.php?act=new');
});

$('#oldProject').click(function(event)
{
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#dialogContent').load('index.php?act=old');
});
```